# How to stop images coming out in black and white in any manual or semi manual modes on my Nikon DSLR?

Tags: nikon-d3100, camera-settings, black-and-white

I have a Nikon D3100, and whatever exposure levels I try all the images come out in black and white if I'm using manual or any other mode except for the auto modes. What could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe you have a creative filter on?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at page 94 of the manual: http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D3100_ENnoprint.pdf

Answer (score 6):

You have almost certainly set a monochrome "picture control". This is probably showing as an "MC" towards the lower-right of the LCD - if it is, adjust this back to SD ("standard").
(That's for a camera running in English; if you're in a different language, the abbreviations may be different, but the principle remains the same).

Comment: Reading the manual as linked by dpollitt above, it's actually that picture controls apply only in PASM modes.

Comment: I want to +1 you already for the fact you used "principle" and not "principal" as I read in oh so many places.